# Cauchy principle value-improper integral

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'd like to calculate 
$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^{1+a}}dx$ for $a \in (0,1).$

I don't know how to start. Would you give me any hint for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: @robjohn  Okay. I will do it next time. In this case, I just want  a hint for the beginning, so that I can use residue theorem for calculating the integral. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an integral that uses a Cauchy principal value. That usually indicates a singularity around which one removes a symmetric region and limits that region to a point.

Comment: I would integrate by parts to get rid of the log, then apply the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula).

Comment: If you want to use contour integration to compute the integral after integration by parts, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216).

Comment: @robjohn: no need for integration by parts for contour integration.

Comment: @RonGordon: perhaps I'm missing something, but on first inspection, with the branch cuts for $\log(1+z)$ and $z^{1+a}$ to deal with, the contour looks difficult.

Comment: @robjohn: yeah, I worked it out, and you actually (in principle) need two contour integrations.  I never said it would be better! ;)  (You end up needing to evaluate Integrate[Log[x]/(1+x)^(1+a),{x,0,Infinity}], which uses a similar contour as the original integral.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that the integrand is positive and the improper integral is convergent. Moreover
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^{1+a}}\,dx&=-\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{\infty}\ln(1+x)\cdot d(x^{-a})\\&=-\frac{1}{a}\left[\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^a}\right]_{0^+}^{+\infty}+\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^a(1+x)}.\end{align}$$
For the integral on the right side take a look at [Cauchy Theorem application](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214293/cauchy-theorem-application).
What do you obtain for the first term? What is the final result?